Unexpected Matlab memory usage increasing when an output of function send to main script
A MATLAB program is experiencing severe memory issues when using parallel processing (parfor). The program generates a series of ECell objects, storing them in a 20x20 object matrix. Despite the total size of this matrix being only about 120KB, the program's memory usage rapidly increases to over 20GB when using parfor, eventually causing MATLAB to crash. This excessive memory usage occurs as soon as one of the parallel iterations completes and attempts to store its result in the main matrix.
Original Code:
Main script
clear
Num_series = 20;
Num_gen = 20;
Cells_series(Num_series, Num_gen) = ECell();
inicell = ECell();
cellpara = CellPara();
parfor kkk = 1:Num_series
    Cells_series(kkk, :) = series_generater(inicell, cellpara, Num_gen);
end

function
function [Cellvec] = series_generater(inicell, cellpara, Num_gen)
    [~, Newcell2, inicell.CellsWhenIni, inicell.ini_t, inicell.ini_tag, ~, ~] = RunTillDiv(inicell, cellpara, 100);
    Cellvec(1, Num_gen) = inicell;
    for kk = 1:Num_gen
        Newcell2 = Newcell2.RenormCell;
        [Newcell2, ~, Newcell2.CellsWhenIni, Newcell2.ini_t, Newcell2.ini_tag, ~, ~] = RunTillDiv(Newcell2, cellpara, 10000);
        Cellvec(kk) = Newcell2;
    end
end

Key Points:
The problem occurs only when using parfor for parallel execution.
The total size of the data structure (Cells_series) is approximately 120KB.
Memory usage inexplicably increases to over 20GB.
The issue arises when a single parallel iteration completes and attempts to store its result.
This behavior suggests a possible bug in MATLAB's parallel computing implementation rather than a simple memory management issue in the user code.
Most of methods related to optimizing memory usage have been used, and the problem doesn't seems related to that, since the biggest data: Cells_series is actully 120kb.

if you think it is a bug in matlab then you should be reporting it to matlab customer support .... not here

What's RunTillDiv? Can you distil this into a [mcve] without it? How many workers are in your parpool?

Thanks for reminding me of matlab support and I am asking for help from them.
RunTillDiv recieve a ECell object (represent a bio-cell) and get the two cells divdied from it. This function runs well in all other cases that I need, and usually, it takes 3 seconds.

Now I am sure the issue is caused by series_generater but I don't know what happened to it. When Matlab finishs the total function, the result will not show up in workspace for large Num_gen (like 20), and show up extremely slow for small Num_gen, also the time used to open Cellvec (the result of series_generater) is much longer than any other ECell array that I used in other place.

Thank you all for reminding me of the MATLAB support team and I ask help from them. Now I see that issue is due to my ignorence about value-type class and handle-type-class.
In my class-ECell, I assgined a Property, CellsWhenIni, which is a ECell array, in ECell define. The default class of MATLAB is value-type class, which will copy the whole data when called in a function. So the actual size of my object incresed expotentionaly due to this repeated copy.
And the soultion is modified it into a handle-type class.
